# What is the presentation of $\mathbb{Z}_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-groups, group-presentation

I am given $\langle a,b | ab=ba, b^6=1 \rangle$ and I am supposed to compute the group that has this presentation. After racking my brains for a long time, the only thing I can come up with is $\mathbb{Z}_3$ since it's an abelian group under addition with two generators, one of which has order 6 and the other infinite order. I tried searching for the representation of $\mathbb{Z}_3$ to try to confirm my answer, but I am not able to find it anywhere. So I guess my question comes in two parts, how do you represent a group like $\mathbb{Z}_n$ and have I come to the correct conclusion in this case?

Comment: $\Bbb Z_n$ is usually presented as $\langle a\mid a^n=1\rangle$ (that being said, even the simplest group can be given a presentation that is _incredibly_ complicated, and there is no standard way to dexode a presentation). How do you figure $\Bbb Z_3$ has a generator of infinite order?

Comment: In a moment of drunkenness or for whatever reason I thought $\bar{2}$  had infinite order, but clearly $3(\bar{2})=\bar{0}$. Not even getting to the part where $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is a finite group. Okay so would the above group be something like $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}_6$?

Comment: That's exactly what it is.

Comment: You're the best, thank you for helping me clear that up!

Comment: A group with an element of infinite order wouldn't be finite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To summarise the comments: $ab = ba$ means the group is abelian. Since no other relator mentions the generator $a$, that means $\langle a \rangle$ is a "direct product" component of the group: the group is $$\mathbb{Z} \times \overline{\langle b \mid b^6 = 1 \rangle}$$ 
which is therefore $$\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}_6$$